# Not able to print or access last character of a char array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to store individual character(including the spaces) of a sentence in a char array like "Do or die"  but whenever I print the array (char arr) it does not print the last character in the array i.e. 'e'.

Can somebody tell why is this happening . I am a beginner in c++.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;

    cout << "Enter the length of the array\n";
    cin >> n;

    char arr[n + 1];

    cin.ignore(n, '\n');

    cout << "Enter the characters of the array\n";
    cin.getline(arr, n);

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << arr[i] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [C++ doesn't have variable-length arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard). For strings use `std::string`. Otherwise for "arrays" with a size known only at run-time use `std::vector`.

Comment: With that said, think about the loop condition `i<n` when you print the characters. What is the index of the last possible character in your string?

Answer (score 1):

1. Here you need to understand how cin.getline(arr,n) works.
2. it will extract characters from the stream and stores them into arr until n characters have been written into arr (including the terminator null character).

So if you change this `cin.getline(arr, n)` to `cin.getline(arr, n+1)` this, it will work perfectly.

Comment: Well, not perfectly. `int arr[n + 1];` is still non-standard. +1.

Comment: then what will be best for this? thanks :)

Comment: As a comment under the question says, either `std::string` or `std::vector`.

Answer (score 1):

**First** in C++, the size of an array must be a **compile-time constant**.So,  take for example the following code snippets:

```
int n = 10;
int arr[n]; //INCORRECT because n is not a constant expression
```

The correct way to write the above would be:

```
const int n = 10;
int arr[n]; //CORRECT
```

Similarly, the following(which you did in your code example) is incorrect:

```
    int n;
    cout << "Enter the length of the array\n";
    cin >> n;
    char arr[n + 1]; //INCORRECT
```

**Second** the reason you're not getting the last character printed on screen is because the size of you array is `n+1` but in your for loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
```

you're only going upto n. You should replace the above with:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n + 1; i++)// note that +1 ADDED HERE
```

A better solution would be to use `std::string` for your purpose as shown below:

```
#include<iostream>


int main()
{
    std::string inputString;

    std::cout << "Enter the string"<<std::endl;
    std::getline(std::cin, inputString);
    
    //first way to print the string 
    std::cout << inputString << std::endl;

   //second way to print the string 
   for(int i = 0; i < inputString.size(); ++i)
   {
       std::cout << inputString[i];
   }
    
    return 0;
}
```